# VB.net splash screen hides modal dialog, but not in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am having a strange error.  I am working on a .net project.  When I build a setup.exe and install the application an modal login dialog comes up behind the splash screen.  When I run the application in Visual Studio 2010 the modal login dialog comes up on to top of the splash screen like I expect.

The code that brings up the modal login dialog is :

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  ... do database loading
  Dim loginForm As New frmLogin
  If loginForm.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

  End If

   ... load fields, etc
End Sub
```

Does anyone understand why I see different behavior with the installed vs Visual Studio?  Any thoughts on how to fix this.

Comment: A splash screen has no z-order relationship with a window owned by the UI thread, any order can occur.  And a dialog always needs a window it can give the focus back to.  You must ensure that the splash screen is closed before you show the dialog.  And you can't use the Load event, there is no functional window yet.  All trivially solved by moving this code into an event handler for the Shown event.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks.  Regarding moving the code to the shown , then wouldn't the form come up empty and the user would have to to watch it populate?  Also, I really do not want any of the processing to occur if the user is not an authorized user.  There would be a lot of data recorded that should not be until the user is authenticated.

Comment: Then you are just getting your code wrong.  You should display your frmLogin normally, not as a dialog.  On the OK button click show your main window.   Project + Properties, Application tab, change the Shutdown mode setting.

Comment: I think that change might be too disruptive since we sometimes require login and sometime not.  Is there a way to just close the splash screen from code?   I tried doing My.Application.SplashScreen.Close and My.Application.SplashScreen.Hide but they throw different thread exceptions.

Comment: Well I tried your original solution of changing things to the show even and I think it is good enough.  Please post that as the solution so I can accept it.  Thanks for all you help.

Comment: I can't post an answer that shows how to properly implement a login procedure like this.  That's very fundamentally wrong, it is incredibly insecure.  Users always re-use the password they use to login to Windows, giving attackers a very easy way to break into the system.